# How to limit loop when using cursor in python

Tags: python

I'm iterating over tweets using :

```
for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, screen_name='@realDonaldTrump').items():
```

But I want just the first `1000` items.

I can define an variable `i=0` outside of the loop and then use `if` and `i=i+1` to check if I've iterated enough. But it doesn't feel "pythony...", more C style

I've hoped there is some trick to it, like:

```
for status, i in (tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, screen_name='@realDonaldTrump').items(), np.arange(10)):
```

Which of course doesn't work

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `islice` to do something similar to `list[:10]`:

```
from itertools import islice
cursor = tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, screen_name='@realDonaldTrump').items()
for status in islice(cursor, 10):
    pass
```

To keep track of the index you can use the built-in `enumerate`:

```
for i, status in enumerate(cursor):
    pass
```